# Collecting and archiving pictures of whiteboards

Tags: images, ocr, archiving

I use whiteboards for work and when songwriting and would like a way of archiving them and organizing them so that I can pull them up quickly later.

Best case it could use some conventions (like date in top right) and some OCR to extract information from the board.

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations Stack Exchange! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.